# Create new sheets based on a list, and populate those sheets with three .txt files that need an insert/loop functionality within path name

Tags: excel, vba

Here is a flowchart of what I am trying to accomplish:
[image: Flowchart]

I have a list of cities:

```
Tokyo
Delhi
Shanghai
Sao+Paulo
Mexico+City
Cairo
Mumbai
Beijing
Dhaka
Osaka
```

Each of these cities has three .txt files pertaining to each in this format:

```
PopulationFile{}.txt
LocationFile{}.txt
CityFile{}.txt
```

Here is the complete list of files that are in the same folder:

```
PopulationFileTokyo?.txt
PopulationFileBeijing?.txt
PopulationFileCairo?.txt
PopulationFileDelhi?.txt
PopulationFileDhaka?.txt
PopulationFileMexico+City?.txt
PopulationFileMumbai?.txt
PopulationFileOsaka.txt
PopulationFileSao+Paulo?.txt
PopulationFileShanghai?.txt
LocationFileTokyo?.txt
LocationFileShanghai?.txt
LocationFileSao+Paulo?.txt
LocationFileOsaka.txt
LocationFileMumbai?.txt
LocationFileMexico+City?.txt
LocationFileDhaka?.txt
LocationFileDelhi?.txt
LocationFileCairo?.txt
LocationFileBeijing?.txt
CityFileTokyo?.txt
CityFileShanghai?.txt
CityFileSao+Paulo?.txt
CityFileOsaka.txt
CityFileMumbai?.txt
CityFileMexico+City?.txt
CityFileDhaka?.txt
CityFileDelhi?.txt
CityFileCairo?.txt
CityFileBeijing?.txt
```

Here's the goal:

- Create sheets based on a list of values (in this case being Cities)
- Use a range to iterate through specific file names (an example being PopulationFileTokyo.txt, then LocationFileTokyo.txt, CityFileTokyo.txt) to paste to Column 1, Column 2, and Column 3 on the {Cities} sheet (example Sheetname: Tokyo)
- Loop insert .txt file data process for each city

Using a new Workbook, I want to automate this process. I want to

- define the city list in VBA,
- then, instruct VBA to create sheets based on this list of cities,
- next, iterate through these sheets pasting the three relevant files for each city in the first three columns
  The script should insert the city name from Cities into the file path/name to correctly insert relevant files to the relevant sheets (as shown after the 'Insert .txt files into columns' box in the flowchart)
  Only the file name in the file path needs to be edited as all of these files are in the folder

Here is a Macro I created showing manual steps of this process (creating three sheets, then going back and inserting the relevant files):

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
' Name sheet, create sheet, create sheet, insert data, insert data, insert data, switch sheet, insert data, insert data, insert data
'

'
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Tokyo"
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "Delhi"
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "Shanghai"
    Sheets("Tokyo").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;/Users/MyName/PycharmProjects/pythonProject7/PopulationFileTokyo" & Chr(10) & ".txt" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$2"))
        .Name = "PopulationFileTokyo" & Chr(10) & ""
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 10000
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("B2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;/Users/MyName/PycharmProjects/pythonProject7/LocationFileTokyo" & Chr(10) & ".txt" _
        , Destination:=Range("$B$2"))
        .Name = "LocationFileTokyo" & Chr(10) & ""
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 10000
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("C2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;/Users/MyName/PycharmProjects/pythonProject7/CityFileTokyo" & Chr(10) & ".txt" _
        , Destination:=Range("$C$2"))
        .Name = "CityFileTokyo" & Chr(10) & ""
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 10000
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Sheets("Delhi").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;/Users/MyName/PycharmProjects/pythonProject7/PopulationFileDelhi" & Chr(10) & ".txt" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$2"))
        .Name = "PopulationFileDelhi" & Chr(10) & ""
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 10000
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("B2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;/Users/MyName/PycharmProjects/pythonProject7/LocationFileDelhi" & Chr(10) & ".txt" _
        , Destination:=Range("$B$2"))
        .Name = "LocationFileDelhi" & Chr(10) & ""
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 10000
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("C2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;/Users/MyName/PycharmProjects/pythonProject7/CityFileDelhi" & Chr(10) & ".txt" _
        , Destination:=Range("$C$2"))
        .Name = "CityFileDelhi" & Chr(10) & ""
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 10000
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Sheets("Shanghai").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;/Users/MyName/PycharmProjects/pythonProject7/PopulationFileShanghai" & Chr(10) & ".txt" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$2"))
        .Name = "PopulationFileShanghai" & Chr(10) & ""
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 10000
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("B2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;/Users/MyName/PycharmProjects/pythonProject7/LocationFileShanghai" & Chr(10) & ".txt" _
        , Destination:=Range("$B$2"))
        .Name = "LocationFileShanghai" & Chr(10) & ""
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 10000
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("C2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;/Users/MyName/PycharmProjects/pythonProject7/CityFileShanghai" & Chr(10) & ".txt" _
        , Destination:=Range("$C$2"))
        .Name = "CityFileShanghai" & Chr(10) & ""
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = False
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 10000
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Finally, the outcome should be 10 sheets named [Cities] with Column 1 containing PopulationFile{Cities}.txt, Column 2 containing LocationFile{Cities}.txt, and Column 3 containing CityFile{Cities}.txt. 30 .txt files should be imported into their proper sheets in the end.

Here is **Python** code that executes creating these files with the content written inside:

```
Cities.txt
Tokyo
Delhi
Shanghai
Sao+Paulo
Mexico+City
Cairo
Mumbai
Beijing
Dhaka
Osaka
```

---

```
readNames = open('Cities.txt', 'r').readlines()
print(readNames)
for i in readNames:
    open('PopulationFile{}.txt'.format(i), 'w').write('Pop1\nPop2\nPop3')
    open('LocationFile{}.txt'.format(i), 'w').write('Loc1\nLoc2\nLoc3')
    open('CityFile{}.txt'.format(i), 'w').write('City1\nCity2\nCity3')
```

If any other information is needed or further clarification please ask!

Comment: I am trying to automate a repetitive 'Data -> Get Data -> From Text - Finish' process in Excel

Comment: OK, so what have you tried in order to do that, and where did you run into trouble with it?

Comment: First thing you need is a loop over your list of cities - everything else builds off that, so it seems like a good place to start.  If your list is on a worksheet then something like `Dim c As range: For Each c In Range("A1:A10").Cells: {work with c}: Next c`

Comment: Thanks for the direction Tim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. But take care to eliminate the strange character from the end of the files name (a question mark in the text you show, and `Chr(10)` in your code, which is not allowed. A file name placed on two lines is not allowed by Windows...). So, `PopulationFileTokyo?.txt` should become `PopulationFileTokyo.txt` and so on. And **read carefully the code lines comments** before running it:

```
Sub testPopulateCities()
   Dim wb As Workbook, foldPath As String, fileName As String, arrTxt
   Dim arrC, cit, arrCol, cl, colNo As Long, sheetN As String, i As Long
   
   'fill the cities array:
   arrC = Split("Tokyo,Delhi,Shanghai,Sao+Paulo,Mexico+City,Cairo,Mumbai,Beijing,Dhaka,Osaka", ",")
   arrCol = Split("Population,Location,City", ",") 'array of prefixes with meaning related to the insertion column
   
   Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) 'create a new workbook with a single sheet
   'insert the necessary sheets and naming them according to arrC array elements:
   For Each cit In arrC
        i = i + 1
        If i = 1 Then
            wb.Sheets(i).Name = cit                                                     'name the first sheet
        Else
            wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)).Name = cit 'insert and name the following sheets
        End If
   Next cit

   foldPath = "C:\Users\RealName\PycharmProjects\pythonProject7\" 'The folder path where the text files exist. Take care of its ending backslash (\)!!!
   
   fileName = dir(foldPath & "*.txt")              'determine the first file in the folder
   Do While fileName <> ""
         For Each cl In arrCol 'iterate between the array elements
            If InStr(fileName, cl) > 0 Then 'if the element exists in the file name:
                colNo = Application.match(cl, arrCol, 0)            'column where to insert data
                sheetN = Split(fileName, ".")(0)
                sheetN = Right(sheetN, Len(sheetN) - (Len(cl) + 4)) 'sheet name to insert data
                Exit For
            End If
         Next
         'place the text file content in an array, split by vbCrLf (Carriage return - linefeed combination):
         arrTxt = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(foldPath & fileName, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
         wb.Sheets(sheetN).cells(2, colNo).Resize(UBound(arrTxt) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(arrTxt) ' drop the array content
    
        fileName = dir()                        'continue the iteration between files
   Loop
   MsgBox "Ready...", vbInformation, "Job done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Fane, thanks for giving this a jab. Using Windows software, I changed foldPath = "" to the folder path ensuring the backslash at the end is placed; the script does create new sheets based on the values in the arrC variable; but breaks at fileName = dir(foldPath & "*.txt"); where the * is tried placing the file name and full file path but it won't insert the .txt files in the folder. In the meantime, I'll try to debug it over it in my side of the globe. Thanks again!

Comment: Forgot to mention that I did reformat the file names to PopulationFileTokyo.txt by removing all question marks

Comment: @bbsmfb Are you sure about the folder path? I observed that you used slashes "/" instead of backslashes "\". Do you use MAC Excel? If not try using `Debug.print Dir("the path in discussion, vbDirectory)`. What does it return in Immediate Window? If an empty string, the path is wrong. Now, I have to close my computer... I will be available tomorrow... Now is 23:07 in my country and tomorrow I have to wake up very early.

Comment: Thank you Fane!

Comment: Using MAC excel, it gave me an error: it says "Compile error: Expected: list separator or )"

Comment: Here are the foldPath = ... that I have tried to insert

Comment: foldPath = "\Users\RealName\PycharmProjects\pythonProject7\"

Comment: Oh wow, so changed the foldPath to slashes instead of backslashes when I ran on MAC Excel and it ran, asked me to Grant Permission to the folder; and now I am getting an error at this line: arrTxt = Split(CreateObject(...

Comment: The error is: Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object

Comment: I'll be trying to fix this today, letting you know what's going on

Comment: Turns out ActiveX does not exist on MacOSX, so I'm going to be doing the project form my Windows Virtual Machine instead

Comment: Windows: When using Step Into debug toolbar tool, the script creates the sheets with the correct names, executes foldPath = ..., executes fileName = Dir(..., executes Do While fileName <> "", and skips directly to Loop, then MsgBox; completely bypassing the For Each loop line

Comment: FANE!!!!!! IT WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I AM YOUR BIGGEST FAN(e)!!!!!! woot woot wow tysm

Comment: Cheers and sending you best wishes for the holidays from the US!

Comment: @bbsmfb Glad I could help! But I still do not understand why it didn't work on Virtual Machine. Did you forget the ending backslash? A mistake in setting the folder, files name? If not, what else should happen to make it working after a while, not at the first try?

Comment: The Excel on the virtual Windows machine running on my Mac works, the native Mac Excel did not because of the absence of Active X; the program is flawless! Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @bbsmfb I remember something abut skipping the loop, but no important now.  Welcome! I have a bad habit: I like understanding... Even if sometimes it is better to let it away, when the result is OK. :)